# Vue.createApp is not working but Is working with new Vue() method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm getting this error `tesyya.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Vue.createApp is not a function`
mycode follows like this:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      count: 4
    }
  }
})

const vm = app.mount('#app')

console.log(vm.count)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>My GK</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="app">
    <h1>this might be challenging for you</h1>
    <ul id="addhere">
      <li v-for="goal in goals">{{goal}}</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="addthis" v-model="enteredval" />
    <input type="button" value="ADD" id="add" v-on:click="add()" />
  </div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="tesyya.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

please let me my mistake I'm a beginner

Comment: Are you using Vue 2 or 3? `Vue.createApp` is Vue 3.x - otherwise you use `new Vue` in Vue 2.x

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `createApp` method is for Vue 3, and the error indicates that you're using Vue 2.  Here are equivalent example apps with correct syntax for Vue 2 and Vue 3.

### Vue 2:

CDN: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.min.js"></script>`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      someValue: 10
    }
  },
  computed: {
    someComputed() {
      return this.someValue * 10;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  Some value: {{ someValue }} <br />
  Some computed value: {{ someComputed }}
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.min.js"></script>
```

### Vue 3:

CDN: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.30/vue.global.min.js"></script>`

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed } = Vue;
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const someValue = ref(10);
    const someComputed = computed(() => someValue.value * 10);
    return {
      someValue,
      someComputed
    }
  }
});
app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<div id="app">
  Some value: {{ someValue }} <br />
  Some computed value: {{ someComputed }}
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.30/vue.global.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 8):

You linked the previous version of *VueJs*

*Note:* Prior to *Vue3*  if you want to link the latest version you have prepend `@next` to the *URI*

It's expected that by the end of this year, the *URI* will be straight forward, even the *docs* will be officially *Vue3*

So, to make use of Vue3 use the below *CDN*

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

Now you can you the `createApp(elem)` api.

Answer (score -1):

You can use createApp function in Vue 3

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.12"></script>
```

Add this script in the header of your index file