# App has already been mounted. nothing show up when open page again

Tags: vue.js, blazor, vuejs3

```js
// main.js

const app = createApp(App);
app.provide('$axios', axios);

window.renderSomething = function() {  

   app.mount('#ticker-maintenance-host');   
        
}
```

the application is developed with vuejs and blarzor. In blazor, will call it

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS;

@code{
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("renderSomething");
        }
    }
}


@page "/dashboard/page1"

<div id="ticker-maintenance-host"></div>
```

first open this page1, all the content can show up. If I leave it and come back to this page, nothing show up. There is a warning saying

```
"[Vue warn]: App has already been mounted.
If you want to remount the same app, move your app creation logic into a factory function and create fresh app instances for each mount - e.g. `const createMyApp = () => createApp(App)`".
```

How can I fix this warning and make my content show up without refresh when coming back.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by moving all the statements inside function block.

// main.js

```
window.renderSomething = function() {  
    const app = createApp(App);
    app.provide('$axios', axios);
    app.mount('#ticker-maintenance-host');  
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mounting your App to the ID `#ticker-maintenance-host`

But all I can see in your HTML is an ID `container`.

Mount your app to the container, or add the ID `#ticker-maintenance-host` to your HTML.

#Edit:

You dont need to mount your view app on every render, just when the website is loaded initially.

Something like this straight out of the docs for Vue3 is how you register a vue app:

```
const { createApp, ref, computed } = Vue;
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const someValue = ref(10);
    const someComputed = computed(() => someValue.value * 10);
    return {
      someValue,
      someComputed
    }
  }
});
app.mount("#ticker-maintenance-host");
```

More reading here: [Vue.createApp is not working but Is working with new Vue() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65149231/vue-createapp-is-not-working-but-is-working-with-new-vue-method)

Comment: sorry, has change that ID. but if I change const app = createApp(App); to const app = () => createApp(App). it shows app.provide, app.use and app.mount is not a function. How can write my code here If I change that line code.

Comment: Sorry i assume you're using vue3, you were correct in the way you instantiated it

Comment: I believe this issue is that your function `OnAfterRenderAsync()` is running constantly, but your application is already mounted. you dont need to mount it on every render.

Comment: sorry, I still can't figure out how to fix my problem. Could you give more details about it?

Comment: `firstRender` looks like its being passed in as true everytime or most times, so your app is being double mounted.